# How to add one extra row to the table using XSLT?

Tags: asp.net, xslt, xslt-1.0

We have ASP.NET application and use XSLT that produces the table, with structure that looks as following:

```
<xsl:template match="Tickets2/Item">
  <tr class="tdNewDesign">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="OddEven = 'Odd'">
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="Seats" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="SeatType" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="RowNumber" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="SeatNumber" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="Ticket">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
              <xsl:value-of select="TicketID" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="Selected = 'checked'">
              <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
          </input>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA; border-right: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ReservType = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="Price*ReservAmount*0.01" />руб.
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="ReservInfo" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </td>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="OddEven = 'Even'">
        <td bgcolor="#fcfae0" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="Seats" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#fcfae0" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="SeatType" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#fcfae0" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="RowNumber" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#fcfae0" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="SeatNumber" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#fcfae0" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:value-of select="Price" />
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#fcfae0" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="Ticket">
            <xsl:attribute name="value">
              <xsl:value-of select="TicketID" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:if test="Selected = 'checked'">
              <xsl:attribute name="checked">checked</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
          </input>
        </td>
        <td bgcolor="#fcfae0" class="text" style="border-left: 1px dashed #AAA; border-right: 1px dashed #AAA;">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="ReservType = 1">
              <xsl:value-of select="Price*ReservAmount*0.01" />руб.
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="ReservInfo" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </td>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </tr>
  <tr class="tdNewDesign" style="display: none;">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm trying to add one invisible extra row after all generated rows, but it was added after each row, which means the number of invisible rows is the same as number of visible rows.

How to make it work?

Comment: You can add new row just before closing  </table> tag. above template is only for row. you need to put new row after this template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to check if you are a last `<Item>`, if so then add the invisible row.

```
<xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::Item)">
  <tr class="tdNewDesign" style="display: none;">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your template is run for `Tickets2/Item`, it will add the invisible row after ever `Item`. Make another template that runs on `Tickets2`, runs the templates for children and then adds the invisible row.

Along the lines of:

```
<xsl:template match="Tickets2>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  <tr class="tdNewDesign" style="display: none;">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>D</td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```